# Visual Studio Check-in Option Changed to "Check In Now"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, version-control

When checking in files using VS 2008, I normally have the option "Check In ..." Recently, this has changed to "Check In Now" and the behavior is different (I'm not given the option to add a note with my check-in). This is bizarre, as I can't think of anything I've done to change the IDE.

Does anybody know how I can get back to the "Check In ..." option? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"The solution is in Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment

Uncheck the box for "Don't show check in dialog box when checking items in""

[Source](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/55_2010_5_0_0_670513/checking-into-source-control-now-says-checkIn-Now-recursive.htm).

Comment: Your link http://www.developmentnow.com/g/55_2010_5_0_0_670513/checking-into-source-control-now-says-checkIn-Now-recursive.htm is broken.